# GetSublayers by Hit test ios

Tags: ios, xcode, view, hittest

I can get a sublayer at any point through hittest at that point by coding. But i want to get all the layers at that point. 
The problem is:
By hit test i can only get the top most layer at hat point, it does not give any information about the layers beneath that top layer at that point.

Is there any way to find all the layers at a specific point in ios?

Answer (score 1):

Hit testing is used for the purpose of delivering events. Since events are always delivered to the topmost view it makes no sense for hit test to continue testing the ones below.

However if you do want to find all the layers at a point you can write your own version of hitTest as a category on CALayer that does this :

```
-(NSMutableSet*)allLayersAtPoint:(CGPoint)aPoint
{
    NSMutableSet *layers = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    if(! CGRectContainsPoint([self frame],aPoint)) 
    {
        return layers;
    }


    [layers addObject:self]

    for(CALayer *layer in self.sublayers) {
       CGPoint converted = [self convertPoint:aPoint toLayer:layer]
       [layers unionSet:[layer allLayersAtPoint:converted]]
    }


    return layers
}
```

Beware of layers with sublayer transforms though. Not sure how to handle that. Usually this is done on UIViews , I'm not sure why you're doing this on layers. Just implement this as a category on UIView instead of CALayer if you want this to work on UIViews.

Comment: What i am trying to do?  I have many layers with similer name(line). I have other layers also. i want to check on a point that either a layer named with line is under that point or not? Note: I have to do it continuously as per second. So i cant make a forloop on all the layers.

Comment: Thats a bit advanced. This is how hit test is implemented (almost) at system level . Check it and tell me if there is any performance issue. We can optimise it after seeing where the bottle neck is.